# Transfer data from Local (XAMPP) Database to Remote (Live) Database

Tags: mysql

I have some data (25k rows) in my Local database table and now I want to go live by copying the data to remote database.

Found some solutions, but not clear how to use the remote server password etc.
Local DB does not have a password, but the remote DB does.

```
INSERT INTO to_database.to_table SELECT * FROM from_database WHERE some_id = 123;
```

Typically if I run the above query in local SQL it should happen, but how to specify the remote DB details like host, DBname, Userid, Password etc?

Comment: Is your remote database hosted on a different machine from the local database? If so you should consider using `mysqldump` on the local database and importing it to the remote one. This will take a few minutes for a medium-sized table like yours.  Otherwise you're in the complex world of federated tables, and you'll be in that world for a day or two as you sort it all out. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-create-server.html  If you're using a CMS like WordPress, use a plugin or an import/export feature to migrate to production.

Comment: YES, my local database is in my Desktop inside my office and the remote database is with a hosting account (I do not know where the servers are located). When I exported the data from Local phpMyAdmin in SQL format it comes to appx 50MB.